Unexpected response from import service: unable to verify the first certificate in Sitecore with docker
I'm working on a project using Sitecore 10.3, JSS, and Next.js in a Docker container.  A few days ago, I completed the setup, and everything was working fine. However, now when I try to start the Docker container, I'm encountering unexpected errors.
I've included both screenshots and text of the error messages below.
Sending package sitecore\package\test.1726029420269.manifest.zip to https://cm.test.localhost/sitecore/api/jss/import...
Unexpected response from import service:
unable to verify the first certificate
C:\Workstation\test\test\up.ps1 : JSS deploy failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1


After that I have added NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHERIZED in .env file then error change as below.

Error
Adding data/media/img/sc_logo.png
Adding sitecore-import.json
Wrote sitecore\package\test.1726055047075.manifest.zip
Sending package sitecore\package\test.1726055047075.manifest.zip to https://cm.test.localhost/sitecore/api/jss/import...
(node:15576) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification. (Use `node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created) Unexpected response from import service:
unable to verify the first certificate
C:\Workstation\test\test\up.ps1: JSS deploy failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo
: Not Specified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1

Has anyone faced the same issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

Hello @Jitesh can you please add also second error message text from image as well.

I have added Error message text

Go through the blog - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2024/08/05/unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate/

I had a similar kind of issue when setting up XM Cloud for local development using Docker container.
To avoid HTTPS errors, set the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable using the following command:
setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS C:\Users\{{UserName}}\AppData\Local\mkcert\rootCA.pem

Note: You will need to restart your terminal or VS Code for it to take effect.

This issue can happen for different reasons. Here are some basic steps to try when you see this error.
1.Solr and Database services stopped. 
2.Switch to Windows containers.
3.run ./down.ps1
4.Stopped the IIS
5.run ./up.ps1

These Steps worked for me.
Hope this help!!

There could be multiple reasons but you can follow some basic steps as generally we do if we get similar kind of error -

Run ./down.ps1
Run ./up.ps1

If this doesn't work then run ./init.ps1
If the above doesn't work then try -

Stop-Service docker
Stop-service hns
Start-service hns
Start-Service docker
docker network prune

And then follow the above steps -

Run ./down.ps1
Run ./up.ps1


In order to fix this issue, you will need to run following command in the command prompt.
setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS C:\Users\{{UserName}}\AppData\Local\mkcert\rootCA.pem

Replace the {{UserName}} in the above path with the user name in your system.
Once you run above command, make sure you close the command prompt and start the new session to spin up containers.
Note: This step is specified inside the init.ps1 file, wherein to avoid certificate errors, we need to set above environmental variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
